# Starting a Sentence with "Because"

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence correct, regarding the starting of the sentence with "because" followed by a comma?

> Because, I have more of it, then I know what to do with.

Comment: See [Should we not start sentences with "And" , "But" ,"So" and "Because"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/561/should-we-not-start-sentences-with-and-but-so-and-because)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking if one can start a sentence with *because* (which one can) or if one  does, does one need to place a comma after it. The answer to the second question is it depends.  A sentence such as yours doesn't need it, and placing a comma there makes the sentence awkward. The same is true of the other comma. You don't need either one.

Comment: In your example, did you mean "then" or "than"

Comment: Yes, providing there is a main clause somewhere. In your example, "because" is a preposition so the whole expression is just a PP which cannot stand as a main clause (complete sentence), but merely function as a dependent in some larger construction.

Answer (score -1):

MY INITIAL RESPONSE

A few improvements are possible here.

First, I think that you wanted the word "[than](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/than)" where you wrote the word "[then](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then)." It is easy to confuse these words.

I would also remove those commas.

Next, the word *because* is a subordinating conjunction. This means that it creates a dependent clause, not an independent clause. So the words "because I have more of it than I know what to do with" are not a sentence. See [here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/subordinating-conjunctions.html) or [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Subordinating-Conjunctions.htm) for some discussion of this point.

You could grammatically say "I have more of it than I know what to do with." Or you could use *because* to join that thought to an independent clause: "I gave some candy away because I have more of it than I know what to do with."

AND LATER...

After re-reading the question, answer and comments in the afternoon, I realized that the title of the post, "Starting a Sentence with "Because,"" attracted more attention from my colleagues than it attracted from me.

You may certainly begin a sentence with the word *because*, but the sentence must contain an independent clause in addition to the dependent clause that contains that *because*.

BAD GRAMMAR:

- I bought two pies. Because I really, really like pie.

GOOD GRAMMAR:

- I bought two pies because I really, really like pie.
- Because I really, really like pie, I bought two pies.

The bad grammar treats the dependent clause ("Because I really, really like pie") as if it were an independent clause. The problem is not exactly the placement of the word *because*. Good and bad examples can both begin with the word *because*.

Comment: @Clare I did not object to starting a sentence with because. The example there, at the end of the 10-point answer, is a complete sentence: Because he was hungry, he went to the store. It would be the same as if the order of the clauses were reversed: He went to the store because he was hungry.

Comment: I take "because" to be a preposition, so it's not a clause at all but a preposition phrase. For those who take "because" as a subordinator, it's a dependent clause. Either way, it is not a main clause/sentence.

Comment: @BillJ What's the object of the preposition?

Comment: It doesn't have an 'object' - it has the clause "I have more of it than I know what to do with" as complement. Prepositions don't take just NPs as complement, but also predicatives, PPs, ADvPs and subordinate clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Is it equally possible to describe every subordinating conjunction as a preposition? I'm not sure if there's a substantive difference here between your analysis of the original question and mine.

Comment: No, subordinators have different properties to prepositions and hence belong in a distinct class. In very modern grammar, only five subordinators are identified: "that", "for", "to", "whether" and "if"; all the other subordinators in trad grammar are reanalysed as prepositions. In terms of answering the OP's question, as I said, it doesn't make much difference since their example is not a main clause and hence not a sentence.

Comment: @BillJ Can you tell me -- in chat, if that's more proper -- why "I asked him whether he had attended" involves a subordinating conjunction while "I asked him because he had attended" involves a preposition?

Comment: It's a big topic that would take a lot of explaining. May I suggest that you take a look at this article by Professor Geoff Pullum. I think you'll find it fascinating: [link](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/01/16/because_why_the_word_is_not_a_conjunction_as_dictionaries_have_it_but_instead.html)

Comment: @Chaim: Good answer but did you mislabel GOOD and BAD Grammar?

Comment: @smatterer Yeah, that's a point. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You say *You may certainly begin a sentence with the word because, but the sentence **must** contain an independent clause in addition to the dependent clause that contains that because*, which I don't agree with. Because I don't. Because it's prescriptive.